# Trying to make a python recursive function that checks if a character is in the given string however i have failed to

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, substring

```
def q5(s,c):
  if s == "": 
    return s
  elif c != s[0]:
    return False
  else:
    return True
  return q5(s[1:], c)
```

Takes an string s and a single-character string c as inputs and uses recursion to determine if s contains the character c, returning True if it does and False if it does not.
and I'm using  recursion to process s one character at a time and determine if c is contained in s.

Args:
s (str): input string
,     c (str): single character

**Im having issues doing this and when I do q5("HI", "H") it returns true because "H" is in "HI" however when I do q5("HI", "I") it returns false even though "I" is also in the string "HI".**

Comment: If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: You have multiple `return` statements. If `c != s[0]` you return `False`, which ends execution of the function. Your final "recursive" return statement never executes.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
You haven't tried to diagnose the problem yourself; a simple `print` statement or two, to trace values and execution flow, will show your misplaced `return`.

Comment: Hi, please undelete your post. Or can you tell me why you deleted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're returning `False` if the first character doesn't match. You need to return `True` if it *does* match and then recurse if it doesn't; eventually you return `False` if you get to the end of the string.

```
def q5(s,c):
  if s == "": 
    return False
  elif c == s[0]:
    return True
  else:
    return q5(s[1:], c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to know if the first character of the string equals the search character `or` that character occurs in the rest of the string.

You can translate that idea directly and very succinctly with:

```
def q5(s,c):
    if s == "": 
        return False
    return s[0] == c or q5(s[1:], c)

q5("HI", "I")
# True
q5("HI", "H")
# True
q5("HI", "f")
# False
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a simpler way to achieve this without needing recursion, you can check for the letter like so:

```
def q5(s,c):
    if c in s:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```